# How to force a blank space in a text array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So I'm coding a random phrase generator.
But I can't get a blank space after each part of my sentence...

It doesn't work when I write a blank space in the arrays, nor it doesn't work when I put a `&nbsp;` between my divs printing the phrase parts...

Can you help me ? i've been working on this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/leokaj/wyndk9dk/14/

```
var adjective = [
  'an amazing ',
  'a luxurious ',
  'a crazy ',
  'an imaginary ',
  'a fun ',
  ],
  //the current adjectives length
  maxAdjective = adjective.length;
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: unfortunately a whitespace not followed by anything is ignored on div elements, 2 easy solutions are changing your .html(something) to .html(something+'&nbsp;'). Another is just adding a margin-left of 5px to your divs

Comment: @juvian on _block_ elements, not on `div` elements in particular.

Comment: For a simpler and more robust way to make your sentences, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyndk9dk/25/) , this method addresses your question in the comments below of *"any idea on how to have differents nouns/adjectives at the end of the sentence ?"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is parsing those spaces out.

You can add a space explicitly with an [escape character](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) like this:

```
$(selector).html(randomVerb + "&nbsp;");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgzocwd2/1/

Comment: Ok i'll try this and tell you :) thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: @LéoKajCbnns It would be nice if you could accept this answer if you feel like it fits your needs (by clicking the `check` icon).

Comment: yes it just told me to wait 9 more minutes when i wanted to click on it :)

Comment: any idea on how to have differents nouns/adjectives at the end of the sentence ?

Comment: @LéoKajCbnns can you ask "*any idea on how to have differents nouns/adjectives at the end of the sentence*",  as a new question? I'd like to show you how I would do it but it would not fit as an answer here

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this with some css, but it might not be as clean

```
.parts:after {
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyndk9dk/21/)

Comment: Personally, I feel like this is the cleanest solution since you write it once then never have to worry about it again whereas the other answer here must be applied each time you append content

Comment: Also you don't need the manual spaces `&nbsp;` between the `.parts`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to display block elements inline. Just set the display to `inline` and ditch the `float:left`:

```
.parts {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: At first I missed that you also removed the `float:left;` but yeah, this should probably be the selected answer!

Answer (score 0):

surely it would be better to use a `<p>` with spans in it rather than a series of divs. As follows:

```
<p id="fullSentence"><span class="parts random-adjective"></span> <span class="parts random-noun"></span> <span class="parts random-context"></span> <span class="parts random-verb"></span> <span class="parts random-adjective"></span> <span class="parts random-noun"></span>.</p>
```

I just tested it in the fiddle (after removing the float in the css and it gave me this:

```
an imaginary rabit on a quest fishing with an imaginary rabit .
```

I would also have a function to capitalise the first letter of the phrase and I also added a full stop. But using a p element with spans seems more correct than a series of divs.

Comment: i don't really need a capital letter on the begining since my text will be uppercase :) but would you know how to get different adjectives/nouns ate the beginin and the end of my sentence ?

Comment: call them different names ( class="parts random-noun1") at hthe start and ( class="parts random-noun2") at the end. Then its just a matter of calling the different parts to that naming structure

Comment: @gavgrif that would be a really poor way to solve that second part

Comment: @DelightedD0D  why? the OP wants two different words for each end of the phrase - using a single class means that the same value will be assigned to each

Comment: It adds more complexity and more code to existing code that is already needlessly bloated with functions and calls to those functions. You should never have multiple functions each targeting separate elements like this. Instead the OP should look at making their code simpler and more abstract. All of this can be done with one simple function, and a json object and with FAR less code, see  http://jsfiddle.net/wyndk9dk/25/

Comment: Dont get me wrong, your way would work, there are just better ways to get there ;)   (speaking of the second part)

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach, but I was trying to stay within the confines / structure of the OP's code. I wouldn't do it that way at all. Incidentally, if you are trying to remove code bloat, wouldn't you remove all those (class="parts") in the divs. They don't seem to be used. also although I like your  code, it would seem that it is adding elements to the dom on each iteration. It would be much better to remove all the individual divs, build the single sentence in the function and then add it to the sentence div in one pass, therefore reducing the number of times the dom is updated.